# Python regex syntax

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner in python regex. so can someone help me understand following syntax?

```
r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$'
```

I came across that statement while learning Django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression broken down:

- `^`: match at the start of the string
- `(?P<pk>\d+)`: Match 1 or more digits (0-9) and capture that as the named group `pk`
- `/results/`: Match the literal text `/results/`
- `$`: Match at the end of the string.

So a URL path that starts with digits, followed by the text `/results/` matches:

```
1234/results/
42/results/
3/results/
```

but anything else does not.

If used in a Django url configuration, the digits are captured and passed into the attached view as the `pk` keyword parameter.

Comment: +1 because, well, anyone who can make sense of any but the most trivial regex gets a +1 by default.

Comment: thanx dude . i really needed the help